# Apply approxfun by factors in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to apply the `approxfun` to a data frame by factors to interpolate concentrations that are not included in the original data frame then bind the results to the original data.
While i know how to do that in basic R but i had trouble grouping_by factors in the data.

Here is an example in R:

```
library(dplyr)

#generate example data frame
time <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10)
conc <- c(0,5,10,15,20,40)
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(time,conc))
df2 <- expand.grid(pH=1:2,form=1:2, time = time)
orgdf <- full_join(df2,df1)
orgdf <- arrange(orgdf, pH, form,time)

#just to make conc different
orgdf$conc[orgdf$pH==1 & orgdf$form==1] <- orgdf$conc*1.1
orgdf$conc[orgdf$pH==2] <- orgdf$conc*0.9

#this is the original data frame
orgdf
names(orgdf)
```

Here how i do in basic R for `pH==1` and `FORM ==1` as an example.

```
timesorg <- orgdf$time[orgdf$pH==1 & orgdf$form==1]
concorg <-  orgdf$conc[orgdf$pH==1 & orgdf$form==1]

timesnew <- c(1,3,5,6.5,7,7.5)

#Find the linear interpolated conc corresponding to these times 
predfunc <- approxfun(timesorg,concorg)
predint <- predfunc(timesnew)
predint
```

however, I want a way to apply this by `pH` and `form` on the `orgdf` in one go, then bind the new times and their corresponding predicted conc to the orginal data frame.

Comment: Yes apply by pH and form. But no it should give different predint as it should use the `time` and `conc` for that particular `pH` and `form` each times it is doing the prediction for the new times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could add `timesnew` to the dataframe and create a function which calculates predicted values

```
orgdf$timesnew <- timesnew

apply_fun <- function(timesnew, timesorg, concorg) {
    predfunc <- approxfun(timesorg,concorg)
    predfunc(timesnew)
}
```

and apply it by group

```
library(dplyr)
orgdf %>%
  group_by(pH, form) %>%
  mutate(predint = apply_fun(timesnew, time, conc))

#      pH  form  time  conc timesnew predint
#   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1     1     0   0        1      2.75
# 2     1     1     2   5.5      3      8.25
# 3     1     1     4  11        5     13.8 
# 4     1     1     6  16.5      6.5   17.9 
# 5     1     1     8  22        7     19.2 
# 6     1     1    10  44        7.5   20.6 
# 7     1     2     0   0        1      2.5 
# 8     1     2     2   5        3      7.5 
# 9     1     2     4  10        5     12.5 
#10     1     2     6  15        6.5   16.2 
# … with 14 more rows
```

Comment: thanks but i also want to add the corresponding timenew to the data frame. so have the same columns i had originally with newtimes and conc added to the same data

Comment: i can perhaps do that by this `df <- orgdf %>%
    group_by(pH, form) %>%
    mutate(conc = apply_fun(time, conc),
           time=timesnew)%>%
    as.data.frame()
df` and then rbind with original data

Comment: @Amer updated the answer. Also you need to ensure that `nrow(orgdf)` is a multiple of `length(timesnew)` (like in the example shared) otherwise it might recycle values of `timesnew` in an unexpected way.

Comment: Yes, you are right. that is the issue i have in my actual data frame. I can perhaps slice the first 6 rows of the factors but not sure if there is a more reproducible way of doing it??

Comment: well, actually this is causing me trouble, it is giving unexpected results. I tried to use summarize instead but that didnt work. Any idea?

Comment: @Amer you need to decide what you want to do for groups where there is less or more number of rows than `length(timesnew)`. Do you want to ignore those groups ? Do you want to fill those groups incompletely with `timesnew` ?

Comment: This is what i want: in addition to the original data times and conc, add the newtimes and predicted conc at these newtimes points.

Comment: @Amer Isn't this already done? as you can see in my answer above. The only question remains is what to do for groups for which they have unequal lengths.